# SQL Statement to get last week, month and year records

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, datetime

I am having some problem when trying to get **last** week, month and year record from SQLite database. My database table:

[image]

I only managed to get the record for today, yesterday, **this** week, **this** month and **this** year.

For this week:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS Total, (substr(date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(date,1, 2)) AS currentDate FROM TransactionRec WHERE  currentDate BETWEEN DATE('now', '-7 days')  AND Date('now') GROUP BY currentDate
```

For this month:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS Total, (substr(date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(date,1, 2)) AS currentDate FROM TransactionRec WHERE  currentDate BETWEEN DATE('now', 'start of month') AND Date('now')  GROUP BY currentDate
```

For this year:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS Total, (substr(date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(date,1, 2)) AS currentDate FROM TransactionRec WHERE  currentDate BETWEEN DATE('now', '-1 year')  AND Date('now')GROUP BY currentDate
```

But I have no idea how to alter the SQL statement to get **last** week, month and year. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this reference http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html . And how date time strings need to be formated to use Date time functions.

Comment: By the way, SQLite does not support strftime() as it would make the program not responding

Comment: `strftime()` works just fine if you use it correctly.

Comment: But I not sure how to implement it into my situation as I've tried it but it does not work

Comment: First try to format your date fields like this YYYY-MM-DD then you may try use date time functions or where statements using > AND <

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using date modifiers.
Just subtract one more week/month/year:

```sql
... BETWEEN date('now', '-14 days') AND date('now', '-7 days')
... BETWEEN date('now', 'start of month', '-1 months') AND date('now', 'start of month', '-1 days')
... BETWEEN date('now', '-2 years') AND date('now', '-1 years')
```

Comment: It works for the last week and year one but not the month. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any idea to get the last month one cause it does not work :(

Comment: `select date('now', '-1 months');` → `2014-08-06`. What exactly does not work?

Comment: When I put BETWEEN Date('now', '-2 month') AND Date('now', '-1 month') the only record which is in August supposed to show but it returns me empty result

Comment: There is no such record in the example data you've shown.

Comment: Sorry but I thought there is one record with 31/08/2014? Even I changed some of my data to August, it still returns me empty result. Why is it so?

Comment: So you mean "calendar month"? Then you have to use `'start of month'`.